# how to create Codeigniter route that doesn't override the other controller routes?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I've got a lot controller in my Codeigniter apps, ex: Signup, Profile, Main, etc..

Now I want to build "**User**" controller.

what I want:

- if people goes to url: **example.com/signup**, I want use default route to "**Signup**" Controller
- if people goes to url: **example.com/bobby.ariffin**, I want to reroute this to "**User**" Controller because the url not handled by any Controller in my apps.

I had create this in my *config/routes.php*:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user";
```

but it's override all the route in my apps to "**User**" Controller.

Is there any simple route for Codeigniter that doesn't override the other controller routes?

Update---

I've got simple regex for this problem, from: [Daniel Errante's Blog](http://tinyurl.com/ykje3fj)

```
$route['^(?!ezstore|ezsell|login).*'] = “home/$0″;
```

where ezstore, ezsell, and login are the name of controller in Your Apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to explicitly define all of those routes. Otherwise you will always end up at the "user_controller".

```
$route['signup'] = "signup";
$route['(:any)'] = "user/display/$1";
```

or something similar. They are ran in order, so what ever is defined first, is going to happen first. So if you catch (:any), you're going to send ANYTHING to that controller.

Also keep in mind that you can use regular expressions, so if you know there is always going to be a '.' in there, you could test for that.

Comment: "You're going to have to explicitly define all of those routes"
Ouch! really strict.

Yeah, I think I should do it.
Thanks for sharing...

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a foreach statement for this. That way you can keep your controllers in a nice neat list.

```
$controller_list = array('auth','dashboard','login','50_other_controllers');

foreach($controller_list as $controller_name)
{
    $route[$controller_item] = $controller_name;
}

$route['(:any)'] = "user/display/$1";
```