# How to route cutom URL with to custom controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, url-routing

I have a PHP CodeIgniter Controller with name `User` and have a method that get details of user `user_detail($username)`
Now when i need to show user data for example for userName `mike`
I call this URL
http://www.example.com/user/user_detail/mike

**My target**
How to make user data accessible by next URLs
http://www.example.com/user/mike
or / and
http://www.example.com/mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read the this [page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) from the official documentation of codeigniter. It covers all related things to Routing URLs easily. All routes must be configured via the file:

```
application/config/routes.php
```

It could be something like this :

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/user_detail/$1";
```

Comment: $route['user/(:any)'] = "user/user_detail/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "user/user_detail/$1";

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by overriding `CI_Controller` class BUT dont change the original core files, like I said override the controller and put your logic in it.

Help: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

[how to create Codeigniter route that doesn't override the other controller routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532595/how-to-create-codeigniter-route-that-doesnt-override-the-other-controller-route)

Perhaps an easier solution would be to route it with the help of apache mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Here is an detailed explanation on how to achieve it: http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/

Answer (score 3):

[Hatem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027083/hatem)'s answer (using the route config) is easier and cleaner, but pointing the usage of the `_remap()` function maybe helpful in some cases:

inside the `CI_Controller`, the `_remap()` function will be executed on each call to the controller to decide which method to use. and there you can check if the method exist, or use some defined method. in your case:

**`application/controllers/User.php`**

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $method)) {
            $this->$method($params);
        } else {
            array_unshift($params, $method);
            $this->user_detail($params);
        }
    }

    public function user_detail($params) {
        $username = $params[0];
        echo 'username: ' . $username;
    }

    public function another_func() {
        echo "another function body!";
    }
}
```

this will result:

> http://www.example.com/user/user_detail/john => 'username: john'
>   http://www.example.com/user/mike ........... => 'username: mike'
>   http://www.example.com/user/another_func ... => 'another function body!'

**but it's not going to work with:** http://www.example.com/mike , since the controller -even if it's the default controller- is not called at all, in this case, CI default behaviour is to look for a controller called `mike` and if it's not found it will throws 404 error.

for more:

[Codeigniter userguide 3: Controllers: Remapping Method Calls](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

[Redirect to default method if CodeIgniter method doesn't exists.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035716/redirect-to-default-method-if-codeigniter-method-doesnt-exists)